# Query process steps of select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have confused with query process steps of select query. I read some docs, select query will run like this

```
1. Getting Data (From, Join)
2. Row Filter (Where)
3. Grouping (Group by)
4. Group Filter (Having)
5. Return Expressions (Select)
6. Order & Paging (Order by & Limit / Offset)
```

I retry test run a query join A table ( 70m records ) and B table( 75m records)

```
 select *
 from A join B on A.code = B.box_code
 where B.box_code = '123'
```

compare with

```
select *
 from A join (select * from B where box_code = '123' ) on A.code = B.box_code
```

I assume the first query will run slower than second query. Because the first query will take time when mapping large data while second query filters box_code before mapping data. But two queries run the same. Why did that happen?

I searched google, it may be related to clustered index, but I am not sure.

1 more question , why clustered index can get where condition to filter data before join ? i think the query will run join before where

Where did I get it wrong?

illustrating images

first query

[image]

second query

[image]

Thanks

Comment: query optimizer can rewrite your queries. Please see execution plan

Comment: for me they look the same, don't they?

Comment: yes, that's what i'm wondering. I think first query run slow , but no

Comment: now you can see what query optimizer can do for you

Comment: can you explain to me why it can do this? query optimizer will run before execute ??

Comment: of course. As you tagged PostgreSQL and Oracle I guess it would be easier for you to read some book about query optimization in the database you use

Comment: The execution plan is better shared as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Comment: I removed the `oracle` tag because the execution plan clearly shows you are using Postgres. Btw: Postgres doesn't have clustered indexes and in Oracle they are called "index organized table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is wrong...

> select query will run like this
>
> 1. Getting Data (From, Join)
> 2. Row Filter (Where)
> 3. Grouping (Group by)
> 4. Group Filter (Having)
> 5. Return Expressions (Select)
> 6. Order & Paging (Order by & Limit / Offset)

Oracle has a number of operations that it can perform to satisfy a query.  Some operations may require child operations to be completed first.  Operations include things like `TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID`, `INDEX RANGE SCAN`, and `NESTED LOOPS`.

Oracle's optimizer decides which operations are necessary and in what order.  It very often will, for example, apply `WHERE` conditions to a row source before joining that row source to another one.  It does that for exactly the reason you imply in your post: because it is probably faster to filter a million rows down to 10 before doing a join.

Oracle maintains an elaborate set of statistics on each table and column so that it can estimate when you submit your query what is likely to work well.

Theoretically, your job when writing SQL is to describe *what* you want and leave the *how* part to Oracle.  In practice, the *how* part is still important, so your question is a very good one.  Read Oracle's documentation on the subject, titled "Oracle Database SQL Tuning Guide".  There is a version for each release of the database and they're available for free online (see: https://docs.oracle.com).

Comment: thank you, clear answer, but i have one question when applying WHERE conditions, optimizer will apply all conditions or a part?

Comment: I can only answer re: Oracle, which the question no longer is tagged as.  It will apply whichever of the conditions it can at each row source.  For example, if it reads a table, it might apply the WHERE conditions on that table and then join those filtered results with another table, then apply more WHERE conditions, etc.